Find a special 4-regular planar graph
I am trying to find a  $4$-regular planar graph  $G$ with vertex connectivity 3 that satisfies the following  conditions:
(i) every face of $G$  is either a $3$-face or a $4$-face,
(ii) $G$ contains  exactly eight $3$-faces, and
(iii) any two $3$-faces do not share a common vertex.
If such a planar graph  $G$  does not exist, then the following assertion  holds:
Claim: If a $3$-connected $4$-regular planar graph  $G$ satisfies the following  conditions:
(i) every face of $G$  is either a $3$-face or a $4$-face,
(ii) $G$ contains exactly eight  $3$-faces, and
(iii) any two $3$-faces do not share a common vertex,
then $G$ is $4$-connected.
Such $4$-connected planar graph does exist, such as:

